# I got a fatal error message when I tried to install the "v4l2capture" package in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, fatal-error, nosuchfileexception

I'm using Python 3.6 and after I tried to install the `v4l2capture` package, I got the following error message:

> *"v4l2capture.c:20:10: fatal error: libv4l2.h: No such file or directory"*

Why is this and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install `libv4l-dev` package in Debian/Ubuntu, or `libv4l-devel` in RH.

Comment: I got the following error message :                                                                                                           " v4l2capture.c:116:9:error:'Video_device' {aka 'struct <anonymous>'} has no member named 'ob_type'; did you mean 'ob_base'?  "    @isalgueiro

Comment: Seems that v4l2capture doesn't support python 3. Install doesn't fail for me using python 2.7.

Comment: Can you access analog camera with this package? In addition, this package was used with python3. https://github.com/atareao/python3-v4l2capture/blob/master/capture_picture.py